# Adjusting variables values, compiling the script and showing the graph..all done in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, variables, plot

So i got this Python script that goes like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



api_url = "https://hydro.eaufrance.fr/sitehydro/ajax/M5300010/series"


# Définir Nmax et D
Nmax = 5  # Nombre maximum de maximums à afficher
D = 20 # Nombre de jours avant et après le maximum

#créer Excel sheet

excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('combined plot.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')




###rest of the code..





index = 0 

for i in  Listes_valeurs_norm_upd:
    plt.plot(i[1],i[0]/max(i[0]), label=f'la courbe du maximum {index +1}', markersize=2)
    
    plt.legend()
    
    index +=1
    
plt.plot(curve_norm[1],curve_norm[0],label='la courbe du débit normalisée',linewidth=5,alpha=1.0,color='royalblue')    





#title to change    
plt.xlabel('la durée des crues')  

#title to change
plt.ylabel('Q inst normalisées')
plt.title('Courbes des maximums superposées')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)) 

plt.savefig('combined_plot.png', format='png')
plt.show()

image_path = 'combined_plot.png'
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(image_path)
combined_plot_sheet = excel_writer.book.create_sheet(title='Combined Plot')
combined_plot_sheet.add_image(img, 'E20')  

# Save the Excel file
excel_writer.save()
```

My question is the following : can i control the three variables (code's label..which in this case is "M5300010" as noted in the api_url, the "Nmax" and the "D") from Excel by simply giving values to their respective cells, let's say B2,C2 and D2 (Or B2,3,4..), click on a button that ill call (Generate plot) that will be put just under the previous cells, which then will compile the whole Python script and shows me the graph in the same sheet in the same "combined plot" file ?

I'm aware that i should use VBA, but i'm a complete rookie at it and my tutor would like the job done in the nearest terms possible.

So far all i have tried is this :

```
Sub Générer graphe()
    Dim PythonPath As String
    Dim ScriptPath As String
    Dim StationCode As String
    Dim Nmax As Integer
    Dim D As Integer
    
    ' Set the path to your Python executable
    PythonPath = "C:\Users\reda.faiq\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"
    
    ' Set the path to your Python script
    ScriptPath = "C:\Users\reda.faiq\Desktop\excel 2.py"
    
    ' Read values from Excel input cells
    StationCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Plot").Range("B2").Value
    Nmax = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Plot").Range("C2").Value
    D = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Plot").Range("D2").Value
    
    ' Construct the command to run the Python script with parameters
    Dim Command As String
    Command = PythonPath & " " & ScriptPath & " --station " & StationCode & " --nmax " & Nmax & " --d " & D
    
    ' Execute the Python script
    Dim ShellResult As Variant
    ShellResult = VBA.Shell(Command, vbNormalFocus)
    
    ' Check if the Python script ran successfully (optional)
    If ShellResult = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Python script executed successfully.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Python script encountered an error.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Not sure if it's correct because so far it doesn't compile well due to needed adjustments to my Python Script or i believe, but it can also be due to eventual mistakes in my VBA code.

I have tried some variations using `Argparse` , but it just doesn't work well so far.

I should admit i only started this this very morning, but as i said, my tutor isn't the very patient type and i'm a complete beginner in VBA.

So can you guys help me by confirming whether the vba code is correct, or if adjustments are needed, and what more should i add to my python script to make the whole magic happen !

Also, i'm very intersted in this, i would like you to share infos about good documentations that tackle the subject.

Comment: Paths with spaces need to be quoted in `Command`

Comment: Why do you 'need' to do it in VBA? You are using Python so why not do it in Python?

Comment: Unfortunately, if it was up to me i wouldn't bother to even think about vba, but it's out of my hands : it's my tutor who would like to never have to interact with the code and just launch the whole from what he's more comfy with, and that's Excel